# Converting a Decimal to an Integer in Matlab or Simulink. (Not Rounding)

Tags: matlab, simulink

So this maybe an easy question. I have some incoming decimal .12345 and I want to make that 12345. Now this value can change so I dont want to just multiply it by 100,000. For example if the incoming value was .123 I want 123, If it was .3219 I want 3219.

Comment: But it won't be 0.123 because of floating point math. 0.123 is stored as 0.1229999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875 in IEEE 754 float in  your computer. So you need to round to a level

Comment: Is your "incoming decimal" being read from a text file or the like (i.e. is it a character string)?

Comment: And if the "incoming value" is `.1230` I suppose you want something different from when it is `.123` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here's something to play with: (assuming your input is a number (double or single)

```
  f=@(x) x*10^sum(floor(x*10.^[0:16])~=x*10.^[0:16])
```

this assumes a floating point accuracy of up to 16 digits...

try `f(.123)` ...

an additional note, the output will look like an integer but it really is still a double\single. In order to really make it to an integer class  one you'll need to cast with `uint64(f(x))` or whatever [integer type](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html) you need.

Another solution is to cast to string using num2str, take out the 0. and cast back to num using str2num:

```
 f=@(x) str2num(subsref(num2str(x),struct('type','()','subs',{{1,3:numel(num2str(x))}})));
```

ugly but works...

Comment: Brilliant answer

Comment: Perfect! Thank You